# convert xlsx files to xls inside folders and subfolders in Excel VBA or Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to convert xlsx files into xls using vba macro or python code.So far,I could get some help on converting files in a single folder using the below code:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname, saveFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean

Pathname = ""  
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Pathname & Filename, _
                            UpdateLinks:=False)
    wb.CheckCompatibility = False
    saveFileName = Replace(Filename, ".xlsx", ".xls")

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=Pathname & saveFileName, _
              FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

I am now trying to generalize this to all subfolders inside the given folder.

On a larger note,I am trying to build a macro which does the following:

1. Run this in batch mode where the parent folder is constant.
2. Process the code at background and put all the converted files in respective folders.

For example, Max is my main folder inside which there may be Med ,Det,Vis,Liv sub-folders.Inside each subfolder,there will be thousands of xlsx files which need to be converted and placed at the same location where the parent file is stored.

Please help.

Thanks,
Maddy

Comment: Please ask _one_ _concrete_ question per question. E.g. "how to recursively enumerate xlsx files in excel-vba", "how to get user input in excel-vba". Only ask for _one_ programming language per question.

Comment: Hi Kay..changed as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in Python as follows. This will take all the `xlsx` files from a single folder and write them using the same name in `xls` format:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import glob
import os

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

for excel_filename in glob.glob(r'c:\excel_files_folder\*.xlsx'):
    print excel_filename
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_filename)
    wb.SaveAs(os.path.splitext(excel_filename)[0] + '.xls', FileFormat=56, ConflictResolution=2) 

excel.Application.Quit()
```

Where `56` is the format number to be used, these are listed on the [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx).

---

To do this on a whole directory structure, you could use `os.walk` as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'c:\excel_files_folder'):
    for filename in filenames:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext == '.xlsx':
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
            wb.CheckCompatibility = False
            excel.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(dirpath, name + '.xls'), FileFormat=56, ConflictResolution=2) 

excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.Thats working to some extent,but it pops up compatibility checker and waits for my response.In addition ,how do I make run for subfolders as mentioned in my question.Your code seems to take only one path.

Comment: You could try adding the `ConflictResolution` parameter. I have updated to give you a subfolder solution.

Comment: Even with ConflictResolution parameter,I am getting the pop up of compatibility checker for each and every file.Is there any way to suppress those popups and run the entire process smoothly without any manual click on 'continue' or 'cancel' for compatibility?

Comment: Try adding `wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True`

Comment: Sorry Martin,even that is not able to suppress the pop ups.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate it so it is a bit difficult to test, try `wb.CheckCompatibility = False`

Comment: Even that doesn't solve our purpose @Martin.Will have to find some other way for that.

Comment: Hi Martin, excel.DisplayAlerts = False before SaveAs worked for me :)

Comment: It converts the files for me, but I can't open them in Excel due to an error: Excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to post a link to a sample xlsx file that isn't converting?